# What's the proper Machine Learning algorithm for this task?

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning

We know that entities have different appearances, for example, "Barack Obama" may be presented as "Obama", "President" and "Barack Hussein Obama".
Is there any algorithm that can determine whether the three refer to the same entity "Barack Obama"?

Thanks!

---

**EDIT 1:**
I'll provide more details about my case. What I want to do is connecting different entity names in Twitter.

If I send a tweet containing "Barack Obama", some time later I send another tweet containing "President" but without "Barack Obama", then my system should be able to connect the two tweets together, because when I talk about "Barack Obama" and "President" in the two tweets, I obviously mean the same entity.

Comment: I think the definition of semantic equivalence here is the easy part. Things become interesting when it comes to the recognition in different media (natural language, audio, images, video). Can your provide some more description of the context?

Comment: @JensPiegsa I only need to recognize entities in natural language text, would you provide some details about how to judge if two entites are equivalent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Latent semantic analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_semantic_analysis) is one method you may wish to try.

Alternatively a non parametric extension of a topic model, such as Latent Dirichlet Allocation, might work.

Comment: Please would those who downvoted explain their reasoning? I see no reason why the methods I suggested are bad and would appreciate the opportunity to understand.

Comment: On a related note, [LDA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_Dirichlet_allocation).

Answer (score 0):

The difficulty of your problem is fully contained in the sentence "obviously mean the same entity" and you are facing the well know (and very difficult)  **Frame Problem**. 
If you turn this into probabilities you see that proba that president is related to obama highly depends on the context.

I would suggest to look at **Hidden Markov Chains** (as google does) to capture contextual  nature of the problem.